# Does a ruby loop reading a file close the file afterwards?

Tags: ruby, file-io

Does opening a file with block close it afterwards?

```
File.open('test.txt') do |txt|
  ...
end
```

I want to know whether this file is closed at the end of this piece of code or whether I should still be calling:

```
File.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What i want to know is is this file closed at the end of this piece of code or should i still be calling:

Yes it is closed.[IO::open](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-c-open) says

> With no associated block, IO.open is a synonym for ::new. ***If the optional code block is given***, it will be passed io as an argument, and ***the IO object will automatically be closed when the block terminates***. In this instance, ::open returns the value of the block.

```
f = File.open('doc.txt') do |file|
  file
end

f.closed? # => true
```

> or should i still be calling: `File.close() ?`

Yes you can,if your block return the `file` object,before terminating,like my above code.Or if you assign the `file` object inside a block to a local variable as below :

```
f = nil
File.open('doc.txt') do |file|
  f = file
  # your code
end

f.closed? # => true
```

Comment: Assigning a file handle to a variable from inside a block like that makes no sense. Ruby will close the handle, which would be invalid outside the loop. It couldn't be used to reopen the file, nor read from or write to it, it can only be used to see if it was closed, which it was as soon as the block exited.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes..you are absolutely right. OP probably trying to test,if really it has been closed. To do so,I think local variable is the only way to test,if the file is closed or not. But your point is valid.

Comment: It is closed, Ruby guarantees it. I'm sure someone could come up with a convoluted attempt to keep that from happening, but whatever problems that generates would be their own.

Comment: @theTinMan I know..OP also knew that..But for self testing probably asked it here,I believe.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you want to read the entire file:

```
my_data = File.read('my_file.txt')
```